# Como fazer a Controller pegar o Texto "string LinkText" do @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Em minha aplicação surgiu a necessidade de fazer com que um mesmo `Controller` chamada Classificação tenha a função de Reclassificação, com isto, quero que a **`ControllerClassificar`** receba o string `LinkText` do `@Html.ActionLink`  para poder controlar a visibilidade de alguns componentes `HTML` de minhas `View`, sendo elas colunas da tabela existente na `View` `Index` e controle também a visibilidade de alguns campos nas Views `Insert`, `Details` e `Delete`

Ficando assim os links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("**Classificação**", "Index", "Classificacao")

@Html.ActionLink("**Reclassificação**", "Index", "Classificacao")
```

Quero que minha `Controller` pegue o valor **Classificação** e **Reclassificação** e envie através de `ViewBag` para as `Views` e assim controle às visibilidades envolvidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer a ActionResult aceitar um parametro string desta forma:

```
public ActionResult Classificacao(string name = null){
```

}

e no ActionLink ficaria:

```
@Html.ActionLink("**Classificação**", "Index", "Classificacao", new{name = "**Classificação**"})
```

Comment: fiz alguns testes aqui, e estou vendo que tem que ser no método POST, como fazer passar sem ir por url ?